# Save Package body and Spec

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using SQLDeveloper tool and trying to use the feature - 'Save Package body and Spec' in order to create an export file with the contents of the Package Body and Spec in a single file. But while doing so the file is created with blank or empty contents. Is there something missing to do some settings to make this possible?

-

I expect the export functionality to work

Comment: what version of the tool do you have?

Answer (score 3):

We run two queries to make this 'magic' happen.

If you're a highly priv user, access to the DBA_ views, we run this (it's much faster than the ALL_ views)

```
SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE ' || text source,
       line
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE owner = :owner
   AND name = :name
   AND line = 1
   AND type = 'PACKAGE'
UNION ALL
SELECT text,
       line
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE owner = :owner
   AND name = :name
   AND line != 1
   AND type = 'PACKAGE'
 ORDER BY line
```

And then we run this:

```
SELECT 'CREATE OR REPLACE ' || text source,
       line
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE owner = :owner
   AND name = :name
   AND line = 1
   AND type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
UNION ALL
SELECT text,
       line
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE owner = :owner
   AND name = :name
   AND line != 1
   AND type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
 ORDER BY line
```

Your resulting file will have the CREATE or REPLACE code for the SPEC followed by a '/' and then the same for the BODY.

If you have a user with lesser privs, we'll run basically the same query but with the ALL_ views.

Are you generating code from your own schema, or someone else's?

What version of SQL Developer and Oracle are you using?

Try the queries below and see what you get.

You can see what we're doing for yourself by observing the View - Log panel and the Statements section:

[image]